# The most efficient way to structure my firestore database

Tags: performance, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating my firestore database and would like to know the most efficient way to structure the database for queries.

I am storing sports competitors numbers from images in the database. There are multiple numbers per image.

I am currently structuring the database like this:
[image]
The query would be

```js
const number = '1543'

firebase.firestore()
.collection('images')
.where(number, '==', true)
.get()
.then((querySnapshot) => {
  console.log(querySnapshot)
})
```

is there a more efficient way to structure and query the database?

Comment: Do you have a performance problem? Why to worry about it if you actually don't observe an issue?

Comment: @AlexMamo I would like to get it right before the product goes live, so that I don't have to make big changes later. I don't have a noticeable performance issue but if there is a more efficient way of doing it I would like to know.

Comment: For a simple query as that, everything looks fine to me.

Comment: Firestore won't let you perform inefficient queries.  The question you should be asking during data modeling is what queries you need to perform, and if the structure satisfies those queries.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson and AlexMamo for your help. I will continue with this data model.